# BigQuery SQL Concatenating Results to Remove Duplicates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duplicates

Wondering if anyone can help. I'm using the SQL code below to pull data from BigQuery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  t1.StoreNo AS StoreNo,
  t1.Status AS Status,
  t1.image AS image1,
  t2.StoreID AS StoreID,
  t2.ColorCode AS ColorCode,
  t2.ColorDesc AS ColorDesc,
  t3.StoreStatus AS StoreStatus, 
  t3.image AS image3,
  t3.StoreRef AS StoreRef,
  "" AS StoreClosed
FROM
  `Store_Data` t1
LEFT JOIN
  `Sales_Data`t2
ON
  t1.StoreNo = t2.StoreID
LEFT JOIN
`Color_Data` t3
ON t1.image = t3.image
WHERE
  t2.ColorCode = 'green'
  AND Status NOT IN ('Rank1',
    'Rank2') 
    AND StoreRef = 'NotClosed'
```

Field StoreNo & StoreID are the same and they both have a StoreStatus but some StoreNo/StoreID can have multiple StoreStatus while others have just 1, for example:

```
StoreNo StoreStatus
BAL1    DINE_IN
BAL2    DINE_IN
BAL2    TAKE_OUT
DAL1    DINE_IN
DAL3    DINE_IN
LA1     DINE_IN
MIA3    DINE_IN
MIA3    TAKE_OUT
MIA3    DRIVE_IN
TB2     DINE_IN
```

This is duplicating StoreNo as there is more than 1 status, I just want 1 row per StoreNo, to do this I want to concatenate the StoreStatus where there is multiple StoreStatus, so the results should look like this:

```
StoreNo StoreStatus 
BAL1    DINE_IN 
BAL2    DINE_IN,TAKE_OUT    
DAL1    DINE_IN 
DAL3    DINE_IN 
LA1     DINE_IN 
MIA3    DINE_IN,TAKE_OUT,DRIVE_IN   
TB2     DINE_IN
```

Is there any way of adapting the SQL code above so the output is like table 2, i.e where this is multiple  StoreStatus for a StoreNo it is concatenated into one result? Thanks.

Comment: Which table is having duplicate data, is it `t1` or `t3`?

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your select list to only the desired columns, and apply the aggregate function `string_agg()` to get data concatenated :

```
WITH CTE as (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.StoreNo AS StoreNo,
    t3.StoreStatus AS StoreStatus
  FROM
    `Store_Data` t1
  LEFT JOIN
    `Sales_Data`t2
  ON
    t1.StoreNo = t2.StoreID
  LEFT JOIN
    `Color_Data` t3
  ON t1.image = t3.image
  WHERE
  t2.ColorCode = 'green'
  AND Status NOT IN ('Rank1',
    'Rank2') 
    AND StoreRef = 'NotClosed'
)
select StoreNo, string_agg(StoreStatus) as StoreStatus 
from cte
group by StoreNo
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `STRING_AGG` with a `GROUP BY`if the status must appear i a certain order you need an order column i use t3.id, as i don't know the design

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  t1.StoreNo AS StoreNo,
  t1.Status AS Status,
  t1.image AS image1,
  t2.StoreID AS StoreID,
  t2.ColorCode AS ColorCode,
  t2.ColorDesc AS ColorDesc,
  STRING_AGG(t3.StoreStatus ORDER BY t2.id) AS StoreStatus, 
  t3.image AS image3,
  t3.StoreRef AS StoreRef,
  "" AS StoreClosed
FROM
  `Store_Data` t1
LEFT JOIN
  `Sales_Data`t2
ON
  t1.StoreNo = t2.StoreID
LEFT JOIN
`Color_Data` t3
ON t1.image = t3.image
WHERE
  t2.ColorCode = 'green'
  AND Status NOT IN ('Rank1',
    'Rank2') 
    AND StoreRef = 'NotClosed'
GROUP BY StoreNo,Status,t1.image,StoreID,ColorCode,ColorDesc,image3,StoreClosed
```